# Can't set map region in iPad app

Tags: ios, ipad, mapkit

I have an iPad app that has a feature that shows a region in a MKMapView along with the user's location. This used to work fine, but now it always displays the entire U.S. as the region no matter what I set it as. It does however correctly show the user's location.

The code that sets the region is...

```
MKCoordinateSpan span = {.latitudeDelta =  latSpan, .longitudeDelta =  longSpan};
MKCoordinateRegion mapRegion = {center, span};
[self.mapView setRegion:mapRegion];
```

The values for these variables are...

```
center = {latitude = 37.525553000000002, longitude = -121.9351005}

latSpan = 0.0029800000000008708

longSpan = 0.011071000000001163
```

I've double checked, and the center is exactly the location I want, but it doesn't matter what values I put for any of these, I always just get the entire U.S. as the region.

Any ideas what has changed or what I overlooked?

I would really appreciate any help as this driving me crazy...

Comment: self.mapView is not nil, and I know it is set up correctly because it does correctly show my location.

Answer (score 0):

MapKit will be unable to zoom into the user's location if authorization is not provided by the user.

The result can be that only a display of the United States is shown.

Request permission using:

```
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
```

Also add the key `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` to your target's Info.plist. The type is a string and is shown to the user during the authorization request.

Comment: But the OP said: "It does however correctly show the user's location." Without authorization, that should not be possible. So don't we have to conclude that this is not an authorization problem?

Comment: @matt It may have something to do with going between iOS versions where the location services are not completely denied but also don't fully work. I'm not entirely sure of the exact reasons but I've seen something like this before.

Answer (score -1):

Not to put too fine a point on it: you're lying. I ran your code with your values and it works perfectly:

[image]

The code for this app consists *entirely* of your values and your code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@import MapKit;

@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D center = {37.525553000000002, -121.9351005};
    double latSpan = 0.0029800000000008708;
    double longSpan = 0.011071000000001163;
    MKCoordinateSpan span = {.latitudeDelta =  latSpan, .longitudeDelta =  longSpan};
    MKCoordinateRegion mapRegion = {center, span};
    [self.mapView setRegion:mapRegion];
}

@end
```

So clearly you are not telling the truth; you're leaving out something important about what you're doing, because when I do what *you say* you're doing, I get the right result.

Comment: Then what could be causing this? Clearly there is something in my class that is I guess resetting the map region, but I can't see what. The code I posted is the only place in my class that calls setRegion on the mapView

Comment: Well, showing the user's location would cause a tussle with your attempt to set the region. - I don't see why my answer should be downvoted; I demonstrated code that does absolutely work.